Are the two probability problems equivalent?
Question One: $N$ asylum-seeking married couples headed for Country A. It was known that the Country A's government was prepared to take in a total of $M (< 2N )$ refugees and repatriate all those who were in excess of the quota. Assume that the $M$ refugees who were granted asylum were selected randomly. What is the expected number of repatriated couples?
Question Two: A box contains $N$ blank cards. The first selection will choose $K$ ($K$ is a random number ranging $0,1,2,\cdots,M$) cards whose one blank side would be colored red. The second selection will choose $M-K$ cards and do the same operation. What is the expected number of cards with both sides blank?
I thought they were equivalent, and my solution is as follows. I wonder if I am on the correct way or what the mistakes are.
Define the random indicator variable:
$$X_i=\begin{cases}
    1, &\mathrm{if\ card\ } i\ \mathrm{has\ both\ sides\ blank}\\
    0, &\mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$\mathbb{E}[X_i]=P(X_i=1)=\left(1-\dfrac{\dbinom{N-1}{K-1}}{\dbinom{N}{K}}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{\dbinom{N-1}{M-K-1}}{\dbinom{N}{M-K}}\right)=\dfrac{N^2-MN+MK-K^2}{N^2}$$
$K$ is also a random variable with $\mathbb{E}[K]=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}\dfrac{k}{M+1}=\dfrac{M}{2},\mathbb{E}[K^2]=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{M}\dfrac{k^2}{M+1}=\dfrac{M(2M+1)}{6}$. By the linear nature of expectations, $$\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\dfrac{N^2-MN+M\mathbb{E}[K]-\mathbb{E}[K^2]}{N^2}=\dfrac{6N^2-6MN+M^2-M}{6N^2}$$
Therefore the expected number of cards with both sides blank is
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=0}^{N} X_i\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{N}\mathbb{E}[X_i]=\dfrac{6N^2-6MN+M^2-M}{6N}$$

I found the mistake. The distribution of $K$ is not uniform. It seems hypergeometric?

I finally worked out the problems and showed that they were equivalent.
$K$ is also a random variable. Notice that $K$ is also the number of men granted asylum. Then $K\sim \mathrm{Hyp}(2N,N,M)$, $\mathbb{E}[K]=\dfrac{M}{2},\mathrm{Var}[K]=\dfrac{M(2N-M)}{4(2N-1)},\mathbb{E}[K^2]=\mathrm{Var}(K)+(\mathbb E[K])^2=\dfrac{M(MN+N-M)}{4N-2}$.
By the linear nature of expectations,
$$\begin{aligned}
    \mathbb E[X_i]&=\dfrac{N^2-MN+M\mathbb E[K]-\mathbb E[K^2]}{N^2}\\
    &=1-\dfrac{M}{N}+\dfrac{1}{N^2}\left(\dfrac{M^2}{2}-\dfrac{M}{2}\cdot\dfrac{MN+N-M}{2N-1}\right)\\
    &=\dfrac{(2N-M)(2N-M-1)}{N(4N-2)}
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore, the expected number of cards with both sides blank is
$$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=0}^{N} X_i\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{N}\mathbb E[X_i]=N\mathbb E[X_i]=\dfrac{(2N-M)(2N-M-1)}{4N-2}$$
Both problems share this result.
The calculation is quite tedious, and I hope there would be some faster ways.
